# Fill Dataset value with result of queries on other Datasets

Tags: dataset

I have a `Dataset`

```
Masterds =  Dataset@*Map[AssociationThread[{"ID", "Appearance"} -> #] &]@
{{"C01", 0}, {"C02", 0}, {"C03", 0}, {"C04", 0}, {"C05", 0},
{"C06",0}, {"C07", 0}, {"C08", 0}, {"C09", 0}, {"C10", 0}, 
{"C11",0}, {"C12", 0}}
```

where I want to fill the `"Appearance"` value with the number of occurrences of the `"ID"` in the following `Datasets` (the number in the `Dataset`-name indicates the number of occurrences):

```
ds1 = Dataset@*Map[AssociationThread[{"ID", "Val"} -> #] &]@
{{"C01", 11.2}, {"C05", 2.0}, {"C09", 22.3}, {"C04", 0.1}};
ds2 = Dataset@*Map[AssociationThread[{"ID", "Val"} -> #] &]@
{{"C02", 9.4}, {"C02",29.3}, {"C11", 2.7}, {"C11", 18.1},
{"C08", 0.}, {"C08", 13.2}, {"C06", 23.8}, {"C06", 1.2}};
ds3 = Dataset@*Map[AssociationThread[{"ID", "Val"} -> #] &]@
{{"C03", 2.5}, {"C03", 13.2}, {"C03", 23.0}, {"C10", 8.2},
{"C10", 3.1}, {"C10", 3.8}, {"C12", 11.1}, {"C12", 12.2}, {"C12", 3.4}};
ds4 = Dataset@*Map[AssociationThread[{"ID", "Val"} -> #] &]@
{{"C07", 12.5}, {"C07", 3.2}, {"C07", 3.0}, {"C07", 28.2}};
```

The `"Masterds"` should look in the end like this:

[image]

I tried approaches with `MemberQ` and `StringMatchQ` but I didnt't find a working solution. And I have no idea, what an elegant approach could look like, maybe it includes a boolean... Again, I just can hope for help from this very useful forum.

Comment: Do you need those `Datasets`?  They always prompt errors I don't understand: `counts = Counts[Normal@Join[ds1, ds2, ds3, ds4][;; , "ID"]];
Dataset@Normal@Masterds[;; , <|#, "Appearance" -> counts[#["ID"]]|> &]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have noted, there is no need to pre-allocate a dataset for `Masterds`.  We can simply assign it the result of one of the following expressions.

The desired result can be generated like this:

```
Join[ds1, ds2, ds3, ds4][
  GroupBy["ID"] /* KeySortBy[Identity] /* Values 
, <| "ID" -> First /* "ID", "Appearance" -> Length |>
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This expression performs the following steps:

1. Joins all of the datasets into a single dataset (`Join`).
2. Groups the associations together by their *IDs* (`GroupBy`).
3. Sorts the groups (`KeySortBy`).
4. Discards the grouping keys (`Values`).
5. Generates the desired output associations by using the first (shared) "ID" in each group along with the group length (`<| ... |>`).

One might think to use `KeySort` in place of `KeySortBy[Identity]`, but unfortunately `KeySort` is absent from the list of descending operators even though `KeySortBy` is present on that list.

**Simpler Alternative?**

If we are willing to compromise a little on the structure of the result, the data can be obtained by a simpler query:

```
Join[ds1, ds2, ds3, ds4][GroupBy["ID"] /* KeySort, Length]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Comment: I get the same result with `KeySort`. So is the consequence of descending only on performance?

Comment: @alancalvitti I am using 10.0.2.  In my first alternative I get an invalid result (with `Missing` elements) if I use `KeySort`.  The query plans are different, reflecting the fact that `KeySort` is ascending and `KeySortBy` is descending.  In my second alternative, it does not matter whether the operator is ascending or descending, so I just use the shorter-named ascending `KeySort`.

Answer (score 4):

From a functional view, it's not desirable to prepopulate `Masterds` - the tally can be obtained by querying the input:

```
ds = <|ds1 -> {{"C01", 11.2}, {"C05", 2.}, {"C09", 22.3}, {"C04", 0.1}}, 
 ds2 -> {{"C02", 9.4}, {"C02", 29.3}, {"C11", 2.7}, {"C11", 
    18.1}, {"C08", 0.}, {"C08", 13.2}, {"C06", 23.8}, {"C06", 1.2}}, 
 ds3 -> {{"C03", 2.5}, {"C03", 13.2}, {"C03", 23.}, {"C10", 
    8.2}, {"C10", 3.1}, {"C10", 3.8}, {"C12", 11.1}, {"C12", 
    12.2}, {"C12", 3.4}}, 
 ds4 -> {{"C07", 12.5}, {"C07", 3.2}, {"C07", 3.}, {"C07", 28.2}}|> // Dataset // Query[All, All, AssociationThread[{"ID", "Val"} -> #] &];
```

[image]

Then:

```
ds[Catenate, Tally, "ID"][All,AssociationThread[{"ID", "Appearance"} -> #] &][SortBy["ID"]]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

As per WReach's second example if only the ID x tally values are needed, the above reduces to:

```
ds[Catenate, Tally, "ID"][SortBy[First]]
```